# display data in html with angular4

Tags: angular, spring-boot

i'm using angular 4 and springboot to build an app but i have a problem i want to display a count object in html and i don't know how
this is my repository

```
@Query("select count (c) from Contact c")
    int getCountOfContact();
```

my service.ts

```
getContactCount(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:9090/contact/count")
      .map(resp=>resp.json());
  }
```

my component.ts

```
getCountConact(){
  this.dashboardservice.getContactCount().subscribe((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
  },(error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

how can i have the result in my component.html

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual problem? Does your service returns the exptected result? If so, you should save it to a variable and then you can bind it in the html.
component.ts

```js
data: any;

getCountConact(){
  this.dashboardservice.getContactCount().subscribe((data)=>{
    this.data = data;
    console.log(data);
  },(error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

and html:

```html
<div>
{{ result }}
</div>
```

Comment: this solution is not working and i don't have any variable result

Comment: Does your http request have a response?

Comment: but do you get the response when you call it from your application?

Comment: Then the problem is with your connection between your server and your client. Did you add proxy.conf?

Comment: the probleme is not the connection between server and client it is working good my problem is how to get the result in html component i don't know to write a code to it